# Emacs ESS and S-plus ( S+ ) 8.1 compatability

Tags: emacs, ide, ess, s, s-plus

I'm working on a project that is in S+ 8.1, and I am using Windows 7 with the latest packaged ESS from Vincent. The folder to splus.exe and sqpe.exe is in PATH.

Is there anyway to get that version of S+ running in ESS?
R works no problem. S+, however, is nothing but trouble.

M-x S tells me to run from icon, then use M-x S-existing.
Doing so with M-x S-existing causes emacs to hang up and crash.
M-x Sqpe lets me select a starting directory, but then gives the error 'spawning child process: invalid argument' and nothing happens.

I have tried adding these lines of code to my .emacs file (based on some outdated mailing list threads), but the results stay the same:

```
(require 'ess-site)
(setq-default inferior-S-program-name 
"C://Program Files (x86)//TIBCO//splus81//cmd//SPLUS.exe")
(setq-default inferior-Sqpe-program-name 
"C://Program Files (x86)//TIBCO//splus81//cmd//sqpe.exe")
```

Note: I have tried with single slashes as well.

I get the same results if I do S+6, Sqpe+6, etc.

Does anyone know if this is even possible? I am an emacs fiend, so it drives me crazy that S+ won't work in it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: May I ask why not just using R instead of S+? Especially if it works fine on your system

Comment: Haha, knew this would be a question. One of the projects I am working on is porting the code base from S+ to R. A lot of the S+ code uses S+ libraries and still has to be run for other projects until the port is complete.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you should try the ess mailing list: ess-help@r-project.org, https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/ess-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking the ESS mailing list. Turns out that this is an issue with the current ESS. Going back to version 5.14 gives support for Splus 8.1 w/ Windows.